# How do I deal with $\cos(n\pi /4)$ in this series?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, power-series

I need to evaluate the limit

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\,\sum _{k=0}^n\frac{\cos(k\pi/4)}{2^k}$$

I see that this series is convergent because is limited by $1/2^n$ that is a convergent geometric series but I can't define what is this $\cos(n\pi /4)$ so I can't find what its ratio $r$ is. If it were $\cos(n\pi)$, then I should put $(-1)^n$ but what about this?

Comment: Is that supposed to be $2^k$ in the denominator?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can evaluate the series in closed form by using [Euler's Formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_formula) to write $\cos(\pi k/4)=\text{Re}(e^{i\pi k/4})$.

Proceeding, we find that

$$\begin{align}
\lim_{n\to \infty}\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{\cos(\pi k/4)}{2^k}&=\lim_{n\to \infty}\text{Re}\left(\sum_{k=0}^n\left(\frac{e^{i\pi/4}}{2}\right)^k \right)\\\\
&=\lim_{n\to \infty}\text{Re}\left(\frac{1-\frac1{2^{n+1}}e^{i\pi(n+1)/4}}{1-\frac12e^{i\pi/4}}\right)\\\\
&=\frac{4-\sqrt2}{5-2\sqrt2}\\\\
&=\frac1{17}(16+3\sqrt 2)
\end{align}$$

Comment: Very nice. ..+1

Comment: @donantonio Thank you my friend.  I really appreciate it.